# Troubleshooting SKB issues

Tags: linux, networking

Our interface driver fails to allocate memory for an skb.
I would like to know how I can debug such a problem. Specifically, I would like to monitor basic memory statistics concerning the skb.

I would appreciate any information re. this issue.

Comment: [Linux networking: Socket Buffer](http://vger.kernel.org/~davem/skb.html) to be exact.

Comment: Are there any statistics I can draw from /proc? I don't see any in the article you pointed me to.